# Where i can get Binary for Apache http server 2.2.15 for solaris

Tags: apache2, solaris

I need to install apache http server 2.2.15 in solaris 9 .But in apache site ,only source is available for solaris.
Please help me to find binary distribution for solaris 9?
If i have to compile the source to binary for solaris,tell me how to compile the source for solaris 9?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm aware of two sites that distribute prebuilt software for Solaris.

http://sunfreeware.com/

http://www.blastwave.org/

Both of them appear to have Apache 2.2.15 available at the moment.